# how to move files from one folder location to other using python

Tags: python-3.x, ui-automation

I am creating a automation script and my requirement is to move some files from one folder to another and get it renamed in the meanwhile

I have tried using `shutil` and `os` module but none helped me so far

```
src = r'C:\\Users\\XX\\Downloads\\'
dst = r'C:\\Users\\XX\\Documents\\UIPATH_DUMP\\'
regex = re.compile('MSS_')
files = os.listdir(src)
for i in files:
    if regex.match(i):
        src1 = src + i
        dst1 = dst + i
        shutil.move(src1, dst1)
```

The expected result is my file should get moved to the destination location. I am not able to figure out just how will I rename it? maybe `os.rename()` would work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.rename() to move the file to another path as well as rename it.

For example, if the original file is:
"/Users/billy/d1/xfile.txt"

and you would like to move it to folder "d2" and name it "yfile.txt", you can use the following line of code:

```
os.rename('/Users/billy/d1/xfile.txt', '/Users/billy/d2/yfile.txt')
```

Comment: my bad.. os.rename() will not work as since this is an automation script, the file coming in my folder evrytym will hold name in different format. the only thing common in the name is first few letters of filename like it starts with MSS_..